# Submitting form with AJAX not working. It ignores ajax

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, forms, submit

I've never used Ajax before, but from researching and other posts here it looks like it should be able to run a form submit code without having to reload the page, but it doesn't seem to work.

It just redirects to ajax_submit.php as if the js file isn't there. I was trying to use Ajax to get to ajax_submit without reloading anything.

Is what i'm trying to do even possible?

HTML form:

```
<form class="ajax_form" action="ajax_submit.php" method="post">
<input class="input" id="license" type="text" name="license" placeholder="License" value="<?php echo htmlentities($person['license1']); ?>" />
<input class="input" id="license_number" type="text" name="license_number" placeholder="License number" value="<?php echo htmlentities($person['license_number1']); ?>" />

<input type="submit" class="form_button" name="submit_license1" value="Save"/>
<input type="submit" class="form_button" name="clear1" value="Clear"/>
</form>
```

in scripts.js file:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
$('.ajax_form').submit(function (event) {
    alert('ok');
    event.preventDefault();
    var form = $(this);
    $.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        url: "ajax_submit.php",//form.attr('action'),
        data: form.serialize(),
        success: function (data) {alert('ok');}
    });
});
});
```

in ajax_submit.php:

```
require_once("functions.php");
require_once("session.php");
include("open_db.php");

if(isset($_POST["submit_license1"])){
    //query to insert
}elseif(isset($_POST['clear1'])) {
    //query to delete
}
```

I have "`<script type="text/javascript" src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.1.0/jquery.min.js"></script>`"
in the html head

Comment: Okay start to debug. Add console.log lines inside the ready. Does it get triggered? Next, what does `console.log($('.ajax_form').length);` return?

Comment: The code seems fine, open your console and check for errors.

Comment: `form.serialize()` doesn't include any buttons. It doesn't know which button you clicked on to submit the form.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`form.serialize()` doesn't know which button was used to submit the form, so it can't include any buttons in the result. So when the PHP script checks which submit button is set in `$_POST`, neither of them will match.

Instead of using a handler on the `submit` event, use a click handler on the buttons, and add the button's name and value to the `data` parameter.

```
$(":submit").click(function(event) {
    alert('ok');
    event.preventDefault();
    var form = $(this.form);
    $.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        url: "ajax_submit.php",//form.attr('action'),
        data: form.serialize() + '&' + this.name + '=' + this.value,
        success: function (data) {alert('ok');}
    });
});
```

Comment: why on button? If submit by keyboard will bypass click

Comment: When you submit by keyboard, it treats it like clicking on the first submit button.

Comment: wow..for years I never realized that to be honest. Must have been mislead years ago and always used submit event

Comment: ok maybe i was asking it to do too much there. I was looking for a simple way to have a small js file automatically take any form submitted in any way to send it to a big php file which can use if(isset()) to run the correct code for each form and each button.

Answer (score 0):

Your ajax call is working perfectly. You have few conceptual error with your code -

1. form.serialize() will not attach submit button's info.
2. If you want to clear your form, you can do it using something like this

`$('#resetForm').click(function(){
        $('.ajax_form')[0].reset();
      });`

3. Lastly complete your task & return success or failed value to ajax call using `echo` like `echo 'successful'` or `echo failed` etc. Use an else condition with your code. It will be more clearer to you.

Answer (score -3):

Remove the "action" and "method" attributes from the form.  You shouldn't need them.

Comment: Does that fix the problem?

Comment: progressive enhancement...form will still submit if script disabled...bad answer

Comment: True... I can't say I've ever had to do a site that was still functional with JavaScript disabled so that did not occur to me.